# Conflicting limits about maximum number of calls to Facebook API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, call, facebook-fql, limit, policy

On https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#features they say an app has an upper limit of 100M calls per day.

However, the error code:
613 - FQL_EC_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED - Calls to stream have exceeded the rate of 100 calls per 600 seconds

specifies that you can averagely perform up to 1 call per 6 seconds.

Those two limits conflicts.

The FQL is supposed to be part of the API, right? If not, then you can perform up to 100000000 calls per day to the API but only up to 14400 FQL queries.

But if FQL is to be considered part of the Facebook API so, what is the real limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you can't call the FQL 100M times a day does not mean you can't call other aspects of the API. The FQL does have an effective lower limit then the rest of the API.

Comment: Consequentially I should be able to perform up to 100M calls to NON-FQL API objects.
Or is there any official document that negates that?

Comment: I think that is correct but I have not actually tested it my self.